# C2014 error when adding stb_image to visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, stb-image

I am planning on using the library **stb_image** by Sean Barrett to load images into a graphics application. Lib code at the repository below:

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h

Though its documentation is short and clear for me in terms of adding the header stb_image.h to your project, and then:

**Do this:**

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation.

// i.e. it should look like this:
#include ...
#include ...
#include ...
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

when I build it on VS2013, the compiler throws the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space    c:\users\ed\desktop\opengl\stbi\stb_image.h 2318    1   STBI
...
```

At the beginning, I thought it was it was a line ending problem (Win32 LF, Linux CR LF), but it seems not to be.

Any hints of what might be causing this error is welcome !

Comment: Edit the question including the code you've written!

Comment: This is strange. Well, at least it indicates what the problem is, there must be a preprocessor command starting with a white character somewhere, as in the negative example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1795kd9.aspx). Could you please post _your_ includes?